# Windows7 - I can't ping other computer after awakening from sleep

Tags: windows-7, ping, sleep

I have two computers and they can ping each other normally when system is fresh (there was no sleep after last turn on). But sometimes I must sleep my computer for a while and after awake ping doesn't work.

Comment: Do other network services (E.g. internet browsing) work after sleep? 

Also, when you run ping, are you targeting an IP address or a hostname?

Answer (score 1):

By default Windows 7 will disable network devices to save power when the computer is going to sleep, you may have to disable this option.

Go to Device Manager, right-click your network adapter and select Properties.

Now go to the Power Management tab and uncheck the option "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

[image: power management]